# Is there a certain order of steps to be taken when conducting regression analysis?

Tags: regression, interaction, linear, confounding, application

This is an extremely dumb question probably, but I took an applied regression analysis course recently and, while I feel competent enough to do regression analyses on a basic level for future projects, I'm still unsure if there's actually an order to how you evaluate what in a model. As an example, I'm still unsure whether you establish confounders or interaction terms first, as well as whether you keep terms that were significant and had major effects in simpler models, but which become insignificant as the model increases in complexity.

On the same level, it seems like regression analysis, at least when I'm actually doing it, ends up being sort of a back and forth of looking at assumptions, determining whether a transformation might be needed, evaluating multicollinearity, etc etc. Obviously there are certain things you establish in the study design phase long before doing any kind of analysis, but the analysis itself seems significantly less straightforward than I would've thought.

Is there a kind of "formula" to how you do regression analysis (and maybe statistical analysis in general), or is it more of an iterative, back-and-forth process?

Comment: My [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rms) book and course notes are devoted to that question.

Comment: I wasn't expecting to find such a comprehensive text on my exact issues, but I really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Frank Harrell effectively answered the question in his [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562500/is-there-a-certain-order-of-steps-to-be-taken-when-conducting-regression-analysi#comment1035565_562500). I just want to provide a formal answer that directly addresses a couple of issues that your question raises.

Section 4.12 of his [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms) and [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) provide lists of steps appropriate for predictive models, for effect estimation, and for hypothesis testing. Those steps summarize much of what came earlier in those documents and are illustrated extensively with several types of regression models thereafter. As he says in the book (page 95), "These strategies are far from failsafe, but they should allow the reader to develop a strategy that is tailored to a particular problem."

Most important, you need to be very careful if you intend to engage in "an iterative, back-and-forth process." Whenever you use the outcomes to help build the model you invalidate any simple "significance" testing you might have had in mind and you run the risk of a model that works well on your data set but doesn't generalize. Although there are workarounds for incorporating use of the outcomes in the modeling if you can automate the entire modeling process to allow bootstrap validation, it's best to try to avoid that. Instead, start with a full model appropriate for the data and your goals from the beginning. From page 95 in the book:

> The strategy emphasized in this text... is to decide how many degrees of freedom can be “spent,” where they should be spent, and then to spend them.

So yes, it's best to do things like "establish confounders or interaction terms" early on and to do so without regard to the outcome values. But even before that, decide how complex a model you can reasonably fit to your model so you can do that in a way appropriate to your problem.

For details, consult the 500+ pages of each of the book and notes.